# Custom Template route issues

Tags: channel-entries, url, ee3, regular-expressions

I have a template route like the following:

`/{static_country:regex[(zh|cn|usa)]}/{alpha_dash}` which matches a URI like `website.com/usa/about-us` fine and points to my template I've called `static` - this works fine.

However, when I navigate to something like `website.com/usa/sdfsdfsdfsd` which is a **fake** route and isn't a route matching an entry in my channel, it still points to the first entry in the `static` channel instead of throwing a `404`.

I know I can limit this using regex like `/{static_country:regex[(zh|cn|usa)]}/{static_page:regex[(about-us)]}` but that isn't very dynamic if the client adds their own pages as we'd have to update the regex each time.

Is there a way around this at all?

Comment: First of all, isn't there an extra `|`? Shouldn't be `zh|cb|usa`?

Comment: @RobsonSobral Removed that now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### disclaimer

First things first: the documentation does not say it, but isn't advisable to use a route on the first segment. Why? I've no idea. This is something a former EllisLab developer told me.

---

### loading the entry

The [Template Routes](https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/urls/template_routes.html) mess up with the automatic discovery of entries. From the docs:

> Template Routes overrides the default behavior of URLs, if you wish to use a Channel Entries Tag in your template you must manually provide segments for any parameters that are normally set in the URL. You must provide a segment for pagination, categories, and entry titles if you wish to use those in your Channel Entries Tag. Additionally, be careful when using `dynamic="yes"` with Template Routes, this can cause issues if your route does not have an appropriate segment set.

So, you need to deal with everything by yourself. Use the [`dynamic`](https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/channel/channel_entries.html#dynamic), the [`require_entry`](https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/channel/channel_entries.html#require-entry) and the [`url_title`](https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/channel/channel_entries.html#url-title) parameters together with the [`no_results`](https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/channel/channel_entries.html#if-no-results) conditional.

Also, let's give your entry segment a [name](https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/urls/template_routes.html#segment-variables-and-paths): `/{static_country:regex[(zh|cn|usa)]}/{entry:alpha_dash}`

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="static" limit="1" dynamic="no" require_entry="yes" url_title="{segment:entry}"}
    {if no_results}{redirect="404"}{/if}
    <h2>{title}</h2>
    {body}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

### Require all segments

**If you need to set [Require All Variables](https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/urls/template_routes.html#require-all-variables) to `no`**, its default, you also need to prevent something like to match the second segment without the first one.

```
{if segment:static_country == ""}{redirect="404"}{/if}
```

And you need to prevent the `exp:channel:entries` from trying to look for an unparsed `{segment:entry}`. Putting everything together:

```
{if segment:static_country == ""}
    {redirect="404"}
{if:elseif segment:entry == ""}
    [...]
{if:else}
    {exp:channel:entries channel="static" limit="1" dynamic="no" require_entry="yes" url_title="{segment:entry}"}
        {if no_results}{redirect="404"}{/if}
        <h2>{title}</h2>
        {body}
    {/exp:channel:entries}
{/if}
```

Or, you can just enable the "Require all segments" setting.

### Without routes

Or you can create one `index.php` file for every language:

```
/public_html
    |
    |- /index.php
    |
    |- /zh
        |- /index.php

    |- /cn
        |- /index.php

    |- /usa
        |- /index.php
```

On every `index.php`, you can set variables related to the language they load

```
$assign_to_config['global_vars'] = array(); // This array must be associative

$assign_to_config['global_vars']['cv-language_code'] = "zh";
$assign_to_config['site_url'] = '/'.$assign_to_config['global_vars']['cv-language_code'];
```

Comment: Oooo nice, I'll try this now. Luckily this route doesn't require pagination however I have done it on the other routes I'm working with. I'll get back to you in a second.

Comment: Hey Robson, this looks like it works for the most part. However, `website.com/usa/about-us` returns the correct page but `website.com/about-us` throws an error (but doesn't redirect to the 404)

Comment: Let's try to fix it!

Comment: I'm not sure what to do `website.com/about-us` needs to point the to static template like `website.com/usa/about-us` does. At the moment it just completely fails. I can't require all segments because without the `static_country` its meant to load the default UK site

Comment: I fear it's fighting against a rule I have on the `index` template which is this `/{country:regex[(zh|cn|usa)]}`

Comment: One last option? I hope it helps!